# Python readline from csv where first item is the object followed by one or more attributes

Tags: python, json, api, tags

I am trying to readlines where the first item in the line is a main object and the other items in that row are attributes(tags) using python.  For example a line might be "Otter, web, prd, x86".  I need to translate this to json where output "Otter" is one object with three different tags "web", "prd" and "x86". Or where I can get "Otter" with one attribute "web" and run an API call to update for each additional attribute.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out [ask] and the [help]. It would be really heplful if you gave *example inputs and outputs*. Furthermore, it isn't really clear what you are asking, what is the problem *exactly*?

Comment: Are you trying to read a file? If so, you could look at the docs for reading a CSV: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader. In the docs example `row` is a tuple, so your "Otter" would be `row[0]`, web `row[2]` etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think I figured out the embedded loop.import csv

data_file = open('testdata.txt','r')

data_lines = csv.reader(data_file)

for line in data_lines:
 Secgrp = line[0]

 for tag in line:
  if tag > line[0]:
   print(Secgrp, tag) 

data_file.close()

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use pandas, read_csv and then for each line output to_json. check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html

something like this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_csv('csvFilePath.csv')
df.to_json('jsonOutputFile.json')
```